# Teradata and Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, teradata

May know the basic requirements for a asp.net and teradata application.

How to connect to Teradata using asp.net(c# code). I have zero knowledge on Teradata. I know that we need a provider for DB connection. How can we get all those things.

How to work with teradata. Does it work like SQL Server with queries, procedures and all DB things.

Whats the difference between SQL Server and Teradata. Can we find trail version of teradata

After installation how to connect and work with teradata from asp.net application (Most important for me)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> how to connect and work with teradata from asp.net application (Most
>   important for me)

You can download the Teradata .Net provider from:

[.NET Data Provider for Teradata](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/dot-net-data-provider)

For downloading Teradata express and other tools you can look at the [Download Center](http://downloads.teradata.com/download)